# Inputs Won't Align Left Even With Float

Tags: html, css

I want my inputs to align left so they are all neatly aligned on the left side like the image below:

[image]

For some reason even when I float my inputs and paragraphs left, the inputs don't align properly. Floating left makes the inputs and paragraphs strangely stacked. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

As it is right now, the way I have the code set up is the closest I've gotten to the actual result I want, since everything is on top of one another, but I can't get the paragraphs and inputs to neatly align left for some reason. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 760px;
}
button {
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  float: left;
  font-family: Gilroy-Bold;
  font-size: 57px;
  height: 110px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 300px;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
textarea {
  font-family: Gilroy;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 400px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  width: 600px;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Gilroy;
  color: white;
  src: typefaces/gilroy-bold.ttf (gilroy-bold.ttf);
}
form {
  font-family: Gilroy;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: Gilroy-Bold;
  font-size: 95px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
hr {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  border-top: 12px solid white;
  width: 760px;
}
input {
  font-family: Gilroy;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
}
p{
  color: white;
  font-family: Gilroy-Bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>1520 Sedgwick Avenue - Sign The Petition</title>
    <link href="css/form.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='images/favicon.ico' />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="petition.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <hr>
      <h1>SIGN THE PETITION</h1>
      <hr>
    </header>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
      <form>
        <p>FIRST NAME</p>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first-name" placeholder="John">
        <p>LAST NAME</p>
        <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last-name" placeholder="Smith">
        <p>EMAIL</p>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="jsmith@gmail.com">
        <p>COUNTRY</p>
        <label for="country">Country</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="country" placeholder="United States">
        <p>STREET ADDRESS</p>
        <label for="street-address">Street Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="street-address" placeholder="123 Brick Lane">
        <p>ZIP CODE</p>
        <label for="zip-code">Zip Code</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zip-code" placeholder="12345">
        <p>COMMENT (OPTIONAL)</p>
        <label for="comment">Comment</label>
        <textarea rows "4" cols = "50" type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="I'm signing because..."></textarea>
        <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Your labels are sitting right in front of each input

Comment: Wow! That was all it was, huh? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a label thats filling the space and you can't see it because its color is the same as the background color

to resolve your problem you need to remove all the labels between `<p>` and `<input>`

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly the issue. It's all resolved now!

Answer (score 0):

The  gaps before your inputs are there because of your label element
for example

```
<label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
```

you can remove labels like the first input

```
<p>FIRST NAME</p>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="first-name" placeholder="John">
```

[image]